# Get matching value from index within a moving range, not the whole column

Tags: python, indexing

I am attempting to get a match within a certain range. I can find it within the whole column but I need the range searched to be a moving range. I figure I'm close but I can't figure out what I should change to make it work.

```
highMax = max(readDF['Matching?'][i-11:i])
getDateMax = readDF['Matching?'].index(highMax)
if highMax < max(readDF['Matching?'][i-10:i+1]):
      make_VarNames['Found'][i] = make_VarNames['Found'][i-1]
else:
      make_VarNames['Found'][i] = readDF['Date'][getDateMax]
```

Let's say I have a column with 1000 cells, and I need to find a match within cells 200 and 210. However, the current code looks through the whole column finding a match at 33. That however is not within the range I need it to be looking at.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `if highMax < max(readDF['Matching?'][i-10:i+1]):`  equals to `if highMax < highMax:` So it always ends up on `else:` ??

Comment: Sorry, that is true, which has been fixed. The problem is finding the match within the range I needed. Let's say I have a column with 1000 cells, and I need to find a match within cells 200 and 210. However, the current code looks through the whole column finding a match at 33. That however is not within the range I need it to be looking at.

Comment: I've edited the current code to be more acurate

Comment: Your code is little bit unclear to me. Are you trying to extract keys from a dictionary according to their values? (Where values lie within a certain range)

Comment: I'm trying to find a matching value within a moving range. My code at present, finds the first match in the whole column. I can't figure out how to make index look only within a certain, moving range.